# The requested page can't be found

Tags: joomla

I'm a new beginner to Joomla. I'm trying to build a website with a sub domain of joomla (free sub domain). After successfully setting up and installing the database plus other components according to several beginners' tutorials, where I successfully upload several templates, I try to test the link of my website but all I get is this error message:

The requested page can't be found.

An error has occurred while processing your request.

You may not be able to visit this page because of:

an out-of-date bookmark/favourite

a mistyped address

a search engine that has an out-of-date listing for this site

you have no access to this page

Search

You may wish to search the site or visit the home page.

Search ...

Search ...

Home Page

If difficulties persist, please contact the System Administrator of this site and report the error below.

## 404 Article not found

---

How can I really go about solving this issue because after intensive research I have found out that this error message is very common for beginners when it comes to Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

Some Suggestions:

**SEF URLS**

Try using a non-SEF URL to access an article to see if that works.

For example, check in Content -> Articles for a valid published article ID (the article IDs are in the last column at the right hand side of the page) and access the page using a URL like this:

```
http://[your-domain-name].com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=xx
```

where xx is the article ID.

If this works, then your problem has something to do with SEF URLs or URL Rewriting.

You can temporarily disable SEF URLs and URL Rewriting in the Global Configuration.

**.htaccess**

A badly configured `.htaccess` file could cause this issue.

Assuming the `.htaccess` file exists in the root folder of your website (e.g. in the `/public_html` folder) then try copying `.htaccess` to `.htaccess.old` as a backup and reset the `.htaccess` file to the default settings by copying `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess`.

`htaccess.txt` should also be found in the root folder of your website as part of a normal Joomla install.

Test whether this fixes the issue.

**Third Party Extensions**

Try disabling any SEF related third party extensions.

Comment: I tried the SEF URLS option as you advised but it didn't work out still bringing up the same error message still. Then I tried to search the cloudaccess.net control panel where i regisetered a free .joomla.com domain but I cant find the .htaccess file. Can you please clarify where I can access this file in my control panel. I'm a new joomla user so I'm not proficient to joomla control panel.

Comment: From the Cloud Control Panel, click on "Manage" and then "Server" and then "FTP" to obtain the IP Address, username and password which you can then use to set up your FTP connection. You will need an FTP client such as FileZilla or similar.

Comment: I have two issues that are completely making me go mad. I don't really understand how to go about this. First, I can I identify the htaccess.txt file via the web directory folder (httpdocs), apart from that I can't find the .htaccess file on top of that I can't find the .htaccess.old file too.  So do I need to buy a domain in order to easily understand the basics of Joomla rather than using a free .joomla.com domain?

Comment: Second when I try to follow the Modules tutorial and try to upload and install a custom designed module as per the tutorials I do get this error message, 'Warning
JInstaller: :Install: File does not exist /mnt/data/vhosts/casite-1090606.cloudaccess.net/httpdocs/tmp/install_5ce55767e93a4/mod_firstmodule/index.html
Module %s: Could not copy files from the source.
×
Error
Error installing module'....That means I can't load modules that are custom, is that problem coming from too.

Comment: Another problem when I try to test my domain link I get this message now, 'This page isn’t working mzansionlineagency.joomla.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS'.... At the moment those 3 problems have given me headache for the past 2 weeks no matter what I have done to rectify the issues. please help.

Comment: `.htaccess` does not usually exist when you first install Joomla and you need to copy `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess` when you enable URL rewriting in Global Configuration.

Comment: The second issue may be unrelated and sounds like a file permission issue or possibly the wrong path to the tmp folder is being specified in Global Configuration.

Comment: The third issue may be related to the first issue but you have a lot of problems for a free CloudAccess website which usually work fine from the start.